# Convert number to month in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to convert numbers to equivalent month in d3js and I am stuck. The numbers come in the form of 1,2,3...12 and I want to convert them to January, February ... December.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December"];
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([50,500])
                    .domain([0,12]);
   var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
                           .tickValues(function(val){  
                             return month[val-1];
                 });
```

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want `tickFormat()` instead of `tickValues`. Like most d3 functions, the function passed to `tickFormat()` takes both a `data` and `index`. You'll want the index. So you can do:

```
var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
                       .tickFormat(function(d, i){  
                        return month[i];
             });
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, to that's a quick way of doing things. However, if you are working with ordinal data like days of the week, you *might* be better using an ordinal scale.

Here's a quick example of using a scale with axis based on days of the week:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="./d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .axis text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var scale_y = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December"])
        .range(Array.from(new Array(12), (x,i) => i* (height / 12)))
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(scale_y)

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
            .attr( "width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
            .attr( "height", height + margin.left + margin.right )

    var y_axis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top +')')
        .call(yAxis);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That sounds the right direction yet it is not working